# creating a list node with a passed string

Tags: c, structure

```
List * List_createNode(const char * str)
  {
List * dup = NULL;
// dup = strdup(str);//figure this out

if (dup == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "\nString Duplication  Fail 1\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

  dup -> str = strdup(str);
  dup -> next = NULL; // we can also do zero

  return dup;  
}
```

I am trying to create a new list node with the passed string str.
instead of malloc i need to use strdup to get the string which i have done as follows.
the structure List has 2 attributes str and next.

This is what i have .where am i going wrong?

Comment: `List * dup = malloc(sizeof(*dup));`

Comment: yes thanks, i realized that. what should i do next in order to duplicate the string 'str'?

Comment: As it is `dup -> str = strdup(str);`

Comment: thank you very much . it works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?

```
List * dup = NULL;
if (dup == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "\nString Duplication  Fail 1\n");
```

Yes, `dup` is `NULL`.

Try:

```
List * dup = malloc(sizeof(List));
if (dup == NULL)
```

Comment: thats error one . thats stupid on my side. what should be my next step

Answer (score 0):

[strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) can only be used for strings. For creating your `List` node which is a type that encapsulates the string you'll sill have to use `malloc`.

I am guessing that you are not allowed to use `malloc` in order to duplicate the string (otherwise it would make no sense)

So what you would need to do is replace that commented line of code (to be figured out) with

```
dup = malloc(sizeof(List));
```